# Redsys SIS0019 Error de formato en Ds_Merchant_Amount en algunos importes

Tags: php, json, base64

En mi pasarela de pagos online Redsys al intentar pagar un pedido con el importe 128.11 me da error en el formulario de Redsys con el código:

```
SIS0019 Error de formato en Ds_Merchant_Amount
```

La página de pago está hecha en PHP y usa la librería descargada desde Redsys:
https://pagosonline.redsys.es/descargas.html

Ejemplo de código:

```
$amount     = 128.11 * 100;

$redsys = new RedsysAPI;
      
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT", $amount);
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER", strval($order));
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE", $code);
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY", $currency);
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE", $transaction);
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL", $terminal);
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL", $url_merchant);
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLOK", $URLOK); 
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLKO", $URLKO);

$tpv_version="HMAC_SHA256_V1";
$tpv_params=$redsys->createMerchantParameters();
$tpv_signature=$redsys->createMerchantSignature($secret);
```

En otros importes me funciona perfectamente, pero en este no. Y han habido clientes que les ha pasado con otros importes también. Pero si cambio ligeramente el importe, funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado convirtiendo el campo de importe de `integer` a `string` al asignarlo a los parámetros:

```
$redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT", (string)$amount);
```

Al ver la documentación de ejemplo de Redsys me fijé que la única diferencia que tenía con ellos era que yo pasaba un integer mientras ellos pasaban un string:

```
$amount="12811";
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT",$amount);
```

Ahora bien. La causa de que esto ocurra aleatoriamente la desconozco, pero mi teoría es que tiene que ver con la forma en la que se codifican y descodifican los datos.

```
function createMerchantParameters(){
    // Se transforma el array de datos en un objeto Json
    $json = $this->arrayToJson();
    // Se codifican los datos Base64
    return $this->encodeBase64($json);
}
```

Al convertir el array a JSON y luego aplicarle el base64_encode, seguramente no se comportan igual si se usan valores numéricos o textos.

Answer (score 1):

A mí me pasa exactamente lo mismo que a tí, con la diferencia de que mi tienda está montada con Prestashop. Probaré a buscar el código que has mostrado y modificarlo a ver si se soluciona... Porque es muy raro que unos importes funcionen bien y otros no..
Gracias por tu aportación!

Comment: ¡Hola y bienvenida a Stackoverflow.com Patricia! Por favor, no utilices las respuestas para comentar (sé que necesitas algunos puntos para comentar, pero eso llegará, no te preocupes ;) ).

Comment: Es solamente convertir la variable del importe a string antes de asignarla a los parámetros.